# multiple condition store in variable and use as if condition in awk

Tags: awk

table1.csv:

```
33622|AAA
33623|AAA
33624|BBB
33625|CCC
33626|DDD
33627|AAA
33628|BBB
33629|EEE
33630|FFF
```

Aims:

```
33622|AAA
33623|AAA
33624|BBB
33625|CCC
33626|DDD
33627|AAA
33628|BBB
```

Using command:

```
 awk 'BEGIN{FS="|";OFS="|"} {if($2=="AAA" && $2=="BBB" && $2=="CCC" && $2=="DDD"){print $1,$2}}' table1.csv
```

However, trying to be more automatic, since the categories may increase.

```
list1.csv:
AAA BBB CCC DDD

list=`cat list1.csv`
awk -v list=$list 'BEGIN{FS="|";OFS="|"} {if($2==list){print $1,$2}}' table1.csv
```

Which means, can I stored $2=="AAA" && $2=="BBB" ....... into a variable by using list1.csv?

Expected output:

```
33622|AAA
33623|AAA
33624|BBB
33625|CCC
33626|DDD
33627|AAA
33628|BBB
```

So, any suggestion on storing the multiple condition in one variable?

Thanks all!

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts in form of code, please do post sample of expected output along with logic of getting it too; which will help us to understand the question more, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for reminding, added the expected output. And finalize what the script needed,

Comment: Sure, thanks for adding expected output in your question. Could you please do mention Logic of getting expected output too? Like by comparing which columns you want to get output etc.

Comment: I am trying to compare list1.csv content with column2 of table1.csv

Comment: Ok, is list.csv is comma separated? or spaces separated

Comment: spearated by "|". I found I can use join to solve the issue, by compare the list1.csv column1 and table1.csv column2, then filter out the "EEE" and "FFF" by awk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[$i];next}FNR==1{FS="|";$0=$0}($2 in a)' list table
```

Output:

```
33622|AAA
33623|AAA
33624|BBB
33625|CCC
33626|DDD
33627|AAA
33628|BBB
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                # process list
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)   # hash all items in file
        a[$i]
    next                 # possibility for multiple lines
}
FNR==1 {                 # changing FS in the beginning of table file
    FS="|"
    $0=$0
}
($2 in a)' list table
```

Answer (score 2):

Almost same logic Like James Brown's nice answer, just adding here a small variant which is setting field separator in Input_file places itself.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){arr[$i]};next} ($2 in arr)' list FS="|" table
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                   ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                ##Checking condition which will be TRUE when list is being read.
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){   ##Going through all fields here.
    arr[$i]             ##Creating arr with index of current column value here.
  }
  next                  ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
($2 in arr)             ##Checking condition if 2nd field is present in arr then print that line from table file.
' list FS="|" table     ##mentioning Input_file(s) here and setting FS as | before table file.
```